# Question about how to define open sets for continuous rational functions

Tags: general-topology

I am having difficulty doing the following question using the language of open sets.

Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a topological space, and let $f,g:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions.
 
Let $A=\{x\in X:g(x)=0\}.$ Prove that the function $h:(X-A)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is continuous

I know how to show that a rational function is continuous if the functions in both numerator and denominator are both continuous in the sense of how is done in a beginning real analysis course.
For this particular question, for the condition $\{x \in A^{c}:\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}<0\},$ if I want to use an open set to describe the inverse image of the range, how do I account for the two cases where $f(x) > 0$ and $f(x) < 0$ given that $g(x) < 0.$
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is $\mathcal{R}$ supposed to be the real numbers? If so, use `\mathbb[R}` to get $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you for letting me know that.

Comment: Consider the two cases: first, those in which $f(x)\gt 0$ and $f(x)/g(x)\lt 0$; and then the cases where $f(x)\lt 0$ and $f(x)/g(x)\lt 0$. The set of all points where $f(x)/g(x)\lt 0$ is the union of those two, so if you can show that each of them is open, then so is their union. Of course, those will not suffice in general.

Comment: Or use \Bbb R for $\Bbb R$..... \Bbb is the same as \mathbb . And with most (or all?) of the \..... stuff, if applied to a sole keystroke (like R) you don't need brackets, just a space.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin so I write the open sets as follows:$\{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} > 0: g(x)>0, f(x) > 0\}$ $\cup$ $\{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} > 0: g(x)<0, f(x) < 0\}$and

$\{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < 0: g(x)>0, f(x) < 0\}$ $\cup$
$\{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < 0: g(x)<0, f(x) > 0\}$ ?

Comment: My point is that the set where $f(x)/g(x)$ is greater than $0$ is the union of your first two sets. If you were able to show each of those sets are open, then their union would also be open. That does not solve the problem by itself, it turns it into a different, more restricted problem that you may now be able to deal with.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin at ok ok.  I understand.  I have to deal with the other two cases as well.  Thank you.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet thanks for letting me know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h \colon \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $h(x)=1/x$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $h' \colon \mathbb{R^2} \to\mathbb{R}$ be such that $h'(x,y)=xy$.

As we know, $h$ and $h'$ are continuous.

Let $(a,b)$ be an open iterval of $\mathbb{R}$. Then $$(1/g)^{-1}((a,b))=\{x \in X\setminus A : 1/g(x) \in (a,b) \}=\{x \in X\setminus A : g(x) \neq 0, \, 1/g(x)\in (a,b) \}=\{x\in X\setminus A : g(x) =y,\, y\neq 0, 1/y \in (a,b) \}=\{x \in X\setminus A: g(x) \in O  \}=(g\restriction_{X\setminus A})^{-1}(O),$$ being: $$O=\{y \in \mathbb{R} : y\neq 0, \, 1/y \in (a,b) \}=\{y \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\} : 1/y \in (a,b) \}=\{y \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\} : h(y) \in (a,b) \}=h^{-1}((a,b)).$$ But as we said, $h$ is continuous. Hence $O$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. From $(1/g)^{-1}((a,b))=(g\restriction_{X\setminus A})^{-1}(O)$ and from the continuity of $g\restriction_{X\setminus A}$ (every restriction of a continuous function is continuous) we deduce that $(1/g)^{-1}((a,b))$ is open in $X\setminus A$. Since the open intervals are a basis of the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$, this shows that $1/g$ is continuous $X\setminus A \to \mathbb{R}$.

Now, $f \restriction_{X\setminus A}$ is continuous because $f$ is continuous. Hence we are done if we prove that the product of two continuous functions $i,j \colon Y \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, being $Y$ a topological space.

The map $k\colon Y \ni y \mapsto (i(y),j(y))\in \mathbb{R}^2$ is continuous: if $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ it is the case that $k^{-1}((a,b)\times (c,d))=i^{-1}((a,b))\cap j^{-1}((c,d))$, which is open. Moreover the open sets of the form $(a,b)\times (c,d)$ are a basis of the product topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Hence $k$ is continuous $Y \to \mathbb{R}^2$. Finally, as: $$(Y \xrightarrow{ij} \mathbb{R})=(Y\xrightarrow{k} \mathbb{R}^2\xrightarrow{h'}\mathbb{R}) $$ we conclude that $ij$ is continuous, as it is a composition of continuous functions.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer.  My apologises for not responding earlier.  I thought of doing it your way, but i was not able to characterize open sets for function of the form 1/g.  Again thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1):

As restrictions of continuous functions are continuous,
f and g over R - A are continuous.
As g is never 0 over R - A, 1/g is defined and continuous over R - A.
Since the product of two continuous functions is continuous,
f/g is continuous over R - A.

Comment: I think I have to use the open set definition for continuity to answer the question.